# Build Qt project for "android platform"

Tags: android, qt

This is just a very general question about developing android apps with Qt.
Can I build any Qt application I created for the use on android machines or are those specifically set up projects which demand a fully functional Qt-android-setup?

Comment: As long as you're using Qt modules supported on Android, there's nothing else you have to do really.  See this page for details: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html

Comment: Oh, thanks, I wonder why I didn't find that page myself...
So, essentially, as soon as I got this SDK/NDK/... stuff, I can build my applications for android platforms...? What is the difference between the plain Qt installer and the Qt for android installer, if I may ask. I didn't figure the difference, since I have to download the packages (SDK, etc)  separately, anyways?

Comment: @MrEricSir I forgot to address you in the comment...

Comment: @MrEricSir if you could pack this into a short answer (please mind my comment), I'll gladly accept it. :)